# Neo4j "RelationshipRecord[22] not in use" error

Tags: neo4j, relationship, record, cypher

I'm getting this error

```
RelationshipRecord[22] not in use
```

executing this command

```
start r=relationship(22)
delete r
```

when trying to delete a broken realtionship. With a broken relationship I mean with a deleted start node or destination node. For example I had this reltionship

```
(10)--->(11)
```

I deleted  the node 11.

```
(10)--->
```

Now I want to delete the relationship but I'm getting the error mentioned above.

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neo4j won't keep around hanging relations- so there will not be a case where you have

> (10)--->

The relationship would have been deleted already, hence you get that error while trying to delete it again.

Answer (score 0):

The next day I started working with that the problem dissapeared... May be a cache in the webadmin ... or something similar.

Thanks for all!